# Why use datatypes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, there is a Number dataype for both integers and float and a String datatype for both characters and strings.

My question is why use different datatypes like Number, String, Boolean etc. Why not combine everything into one type? or why should we use datatypes at all?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Comment: how do YOU use datatypes?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp

Comment: Is javascript the first language you're learning?

Comment: its not "how" but "why" that i want to know. thanks

Comment: One example: Adding two numbers generates a different result than adding two strings (`3 + 3 === 6`, but `"3" + "3" === "33"`).  Thus, the program must know what type the variables are in order to know which type of addition operator to use.

Comment: @jfriend00 That is a constraint imposed by ad hoc polymorphism, but it's not hard to conceive of a language without numeric types in which `(concat "3" "3")` equals `"33"` and `(plus "3" "3")` equals `"6"`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin - we're not talking about a theoretical language.  We're talking about what Javascript is today.

Comment: @jfriend00 We's talking about *why* javascript was defined as it is, so yes, I think we are necessarily discussing its possible alternatives.

Comment: To make it easier to write applications. Underneath everything is just numbers anyway. But writing a string `"Hello World"` is easier than writing the number that is represented by that string.

Comment: The why is easy, it's because the ECMAscript spec says so. What other hypothetical languages do, isn't really important. The reason the spec defines six types (seven in ES6) is to make it easier to do stuff, and being a prototype based language, it would be really hard to get anything done if everything was just the same type, with the same prototype, and the same methods.

Comment: It may be a bit too late to do. But you could ask Brendan Eich: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich . None of us can really do anything about it...

Comment: My comment was unnecessarily abstract, so I'll rephrase: You could write `concat` and `plus` functions *in javascript* that respectively concatenate and add numeric strings without a numeric type. If you simply eschew overloading, you circumvent the problem that @jfriend00 describes.

Comment: @ChrisMartin - yes, it could have been done that way, but the designers of Javascript obviously wanted to support both `3 + 3` and `"3" + "3"` and thus could NOT do that if they didn't know what type the variables were.  So, Javascript as it exists today must know the type.  And, it's not only the `+` operator that must know the type.

Answer (score 1):

Why abstract anything at all? One could represent everything in binary with bits and bytes, which we still do just not in high level languages such as JavaScript which is [dynamically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language).

Abstracting [types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) lets us define semantics, such as the `+ operator` means concatenation for strings and arithmetic addition numbers, more efficient memory allocations with [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) (`Uint8Array`, `Float64Array`), coming later down the pipeline in *ECMAScript* is SIMD instructions and user defined value types, which may eventually lead to user space operator overloading.

Comment: thanks..but could you kindly edit your answer in a way that could be understood by a beginner?

Comment: @user3243180 anything specific that should be expanded upon or that you did not understand from the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You seem a bit confused.  Java**Script** is meant to a scripting language.  None of that strict-syntax for defining variables is necessary (`int name = 6;` would be invalid anyways), if that's what you were wondering anyways.  Now, onto the real question... (I'm making the best sense of this that I can...)

> My question is why use different datatypes like Number, String, Boolean etc. Why not combine everything into one type?

JavaScript uses datatypes to acomplish different tasks in different ways.  Different datatypes produce different results.  Here is an example with math (integer vs string):

```
 1  +  1  // =  2
"1" + "1" // = "11"
```

This is how the program can differentiate what the programmer is trying to accomplish.

Another example would be for in-script conditioning...  Here is how I would explain with code instead of words:

```
var myRef = 3;

// Would work
if (typeof myRef == "number") {
  console.log("You entered a number!");
}

// Wouldn't work
if (typeof myRef == "string") {
  console.log("You entered a string!");
}
```

In another case, using the `===` operator, it will also measures the data type...  <s>Using plain old `==` ignores the datatype</s> (As corrected from Felix Kling) the `==` operator simply *enhances* comparison:

```
"1" ==  1 // true
"1" === 1 // false
```

Comment: *"Using plain old `==` ignores the datatype"* It doesn't ignore it, it treats it differently.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh, my bad.  Feel free to edit an improve.

Comment: Short version of that is to consider `===` as truly equals, the spec is rather comprehensive about when `==` does what.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct. In JavaScript everything is combined into one type: Object. Number and String that you are seeing are all subclasses of Object. These subclasses are introduced since they have different methods and operators to work with.

However, things aren't that simple. There are also primitives in JS when directly used its literal form. As a prototype based language, everything should be able to have properties. That is why JS wraps primitives into an Object before doing anything with it.

In conclusion, it can be said that there's only one type (with the exception of `null` and `undefined`), but it reality there are also multiple primitives.

Comment: There are 6 data types in JavaScript. Only one of them is Object. String, Number, Boolean, Null and Undefined are primitive types. The first three have equivalents of type Object.

Comment: (typeof(5)=== Object)//false

Comment: @raneshu Explain how a variable of a number can have properties if it is not wrapped in an object before any operations.

Comment: @FelixKling Though `typeof null === 'object'`.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Either there is a single type or there are multiple. And it's not true that primitive values are always converted to objects, only when you are trying to access a property on them.

Comment: @Teemu: `typeof` is basically a lookup table: https://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3. Null is still a data type: https://es5.github.io/#x8.2

Comment: @FelixKling - With all those auto-typecasting going on in this weakly typed language, type doesn't really matter that much anymore. But I guess you are right.